# ImageIO.readImage IIOException while I can open it in Chrome

Tags: java, url, javax.imageio

I can open [this image](http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.20.1/img/champion/Gragas.png) in my browser but it won't load in my java application, why? It is supposed to be a free-to-use database, I can't see why I can't use it.

I'm using this piece of code:

```
public static String getContentsFromURL(String address){

    String contents = "";
    try{
        URL url = new URL(address);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            contents += line;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return contents;

}
```

And I'm getting an IIOException "Can't find input file!"

Comment: Please share the relevant java source. Do you get any exceptions? If so, also add it to the question.

Comment: what is a purpose of having image in String? do you have some kind of specific task? it does not throws exception. works but binds content to string.

Comment: Please post the exact exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
URL url = new URL("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.20.1/img/champion/Gragas.png");
Image image1 = ImageIO.read(url);
```

image screenshot from my debbuger. 
[image]

Comment: Glad it Helped, you can take a Look to a BufferedImage as well. and do not use String like you used contents += line; use StringBuilder instead, and append new string to builder.